# Port forwarding safely or WAN port alternative?

Tags: router, security, port-forwarding, modem, wan

I am trying to host a small server on my home network and I am trying to come up with a convincing solution, security-wise.

First of all, my router has a DSL connection to the ISP, but it also has a WAN port. I was told that this WAN port would be used in case a fibre connection would have been used. My understanding is that the so called "router" is actually a modem+router system, so I am thinking that it would be possible to connect my little server directly to the modem and to the world wide web, without the need of port fowarding, via the WAN port. This way, in my view, the server would be isolated from my LAN in case it gets compromised. Does this make sense?

If the above method is not supposed to work, how can I port forward safely? By that, I mean in case the server gets compromised, the hacker would not be able to reach the other devices on my LAN (so no viruses get transferred over the LAN) or be able to reach the admin login interfaces.

All in all, if someone gets full control of my server then I don't want that attacker to be able to alter my router system or the devices connected to its LAN.

Thanks!

Comment: The mechanism you'r looking for is called "DMZ" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing). You should try to find configuration related to DMZ in your router.

Comment: @S.Brottes DMZ won't isolate the server from the rest of the network if it's compromised

Comment: @S.Brottes Or rather: in the meaning described on Wikipedia it's exactly what they are looking for, but the "DMZ" setting in their router is something completely different.

Comment: DMZ on consumer routers is actually "Exposed Host", which is something entirely different. That unfortunately means it won't help here. // The WAN port will likely not work either, because of software limitations in the router firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting your server directly to the ISP through only a DSL modem is certainly possible. (That's how people used to connect their PCs to DSL in the earlier days.)

But your ISP most likely only gives out one "public" IP address per customer, so if your server takes it, then your remaining LAN router won't have any way to access the Internet anymore.

(Unless the server *becomes* the LAN's router – which is also possible, but would completely defeat the point here, as it'd once again be directly connected to the LAN.)

Also, the router's Ethernet WAN port probably won't work this way – unlike the LAN side, the two WAN interfaces probably are not directly bridged together; it's more likely that they're set up as independent "WAN1" and "WAN2" interfaces, so connecting a device to WAN2 will not give it any kind of direct access to WAN1. (Not all DSL connection types *can* be bridged, e.g. a PPPoE or PPPoA connection cannot be.)

Still, that kind of setup would be fairly close to your goal. What you should try to set up is two separate *LAN* interfaces (e.g. using VLANs if the router supports it), so that "LAN1" would be your main network while "LAN2" would only contain your server. The router's firewall would then be able to control traffic between LAN2 and LAN1, allowing you to connect to the server but not the other way.

Comment: It looks like my router does not offer a feature which would implment this. How about this though: connect a modem directly to the DSL line. Then, connect the WAN of the router to said modem and then connect the server to the modem on another port. Not sure how much damage can be done to the modem by a hacker though.

Comment: @DanielTork Another way to have two LANs is to buy a second router that you plug to your first router, and you plug the server to the second router. You have to define NAT rules on both routers so that the server can be accessed from the internet. And have strict security rules on this second router (strong password etc...)